# linear least square problems solved using LU decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

I have been given this [datafile](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/strd/lls/data/Pontius.shtml)
For which I have to solve Ax=b.  In which A is a matrix, x a vector and b a vector.

The datafile consist of 2 vector one with the X-coordinates, and the other one with y-coordinates. I don't how i based from that shall create a A matrix, because that will make a A matrix on length of dataset) x 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As science said, you have the following model:

$$
y_{i} = \beta_{0}+\beta_{1}x_{i}+\beta_{2}x_{i}^{2}+\varepsilon_{i}, \qquad i=1,2,\dots,n
$$

For each of your data point you have this previous equation (there are 40 equations like that if I correctly understand the data set). You have 3 unknowns for 40 equations therefore you need to perform a regression. $\varepsilon$ is the error between the model and the data that needs to be minimized. You can re-write in a matrix notation:

$$
Y_{(n\times 1)} = X_{(n\times k)}A_{(k\times 1)} + \boldsymbol{\varepsilon}_{(n\times 1)}
$$

where subscripts represent the dimension of the matrices. In your data set there is 40 observations and the model is quadratic, meaning that it has 3 parameters ($\beta$s). This translates the above regression in:

$$
Y_{(40\times 1)} = X_{(40\times 3)}A_{(3\times 1)} + \boldsymbol{\varepsilon}_{(40\times 1)}
$$

where $X$ first column is filled of ones for the constant $\beta_{0}$, second column is the data and third column is filled of your squared data. And $A = (\beta_{0},\beta_{1},\beta_{2})^{T}$. To estimate the coefficient of matrix $A$ you generally end up with the following expression (which is the classical OLS) by minimizing the sum of squared difference between the data and the model ($\varepsilon$):

$$
\ \min_{\beta_{0},\beta_{1},\beta_{2}} \sum_{i=1}^{n=40}\varepsilon_{i}^{2}
$$

and the result can be express in a matrix notation as (to keep things simple)

$$
A_{(3\times 1)} = (X_{(3\times 40)}^{T}X_{(40\times 3)})^{-1}X_{(3\times 40)}^{T}Y_{(40\times 1)}
$$

and you can check that the matrix dimensions corresponds on each side of the equality side.

Comment: How do you know that the you have 3 unknowns from the dataset..  The model itself isn't given in beforehand. The only thing i have is the datafile.  Why couldn't it be 4 unknowns?...

Comment: I assume this model because it is written like that under the section "model" on the webpage. If you start from a blank page the first thing to do is to plot X and Y. With this graph you will be able to see if there is a linear relation or something else like a quadratic relation. Maybe you select two or three models and you fit them to your data. Then you can compare how is the fit visually or by looking at the [$R^{2}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination) which will tell you how much of the variation of Y is explained by the variation of X.

Comment: You can also test the statistical significance of the estimated coefficient by conducting a [Student-t test] ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test). If the coefficient has a sense in this regression. You can also test the overall model by looking at all coefficient at one and apply a [F-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test). You should also pay attention to avoid over-fitting your data. These tests are the basic procedure for validating a regression, you can learn more about [regression diagnostic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_diagnostic)

Comment: Ok... What would the matrix consist of?

Comment: If you want to fit a linear model without a constant (\beta_{0}), X matrix will be vector corresponding to your data. If you add a constant you need to add a column of 1. In the case of the quadratic model with constant the matrix X will be: 1s in 1st col, x in 2nd column and $x^2$ in 3rd col. Etc...

Comment: This would make in a equation Ax = B
A = (82x3)
x = (82)
B = (82)
X = would be 82 variables..  I could transpose A, but 
as i see it X and B has to have the same length.. but that only be 82.. because B is the Raw data..

Comment: Assuming that your data set consists of 82 observations. A is the matrix of coefficient its size will depend only on the number of parameters $\beta$ that you want to have. For the quadratic case, A (3x1). B (82x1) is a vector containing the data points to be explained by your model given the input data represented by the matrix X. If you take the quadratic model X will be (82x3) matrix with, for example, the first line equivalent to (1, $x_{1}$,$x_{1}^{2}$).

Comment: You have 3 unknowns and 82 equations, your system of equations is [overdetermined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overdetermined_system). Therefore, you need to regress in order to have solution that is able to almost satisfy each equation.

Comment: Sorry for confusing you.. I don't know why keep saying 82, since there is only 40 observation.. 
So yes.. The Matrix X = 40x3 , vector A = 3 , Vector B = 40.. 

(3x1)x(40x3) = (3x1)

I see some mismatch with the dimensions.. 
The B matrix should be 3x3 and not 3x1.

Comment: xA = B with (40x3)(3x1)=(40x1)
or
A'x = B' with (1x3)(3x40) = (1x40)

Comment: Somehow i mess up with the rows of X and A... they become not equal to each other.. how come..

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you get the matrix. You substitute the pairs $(x_i,y_i)$ in the model

$$ y = \beta_0+\beta_1 x +\beta_2 x^2 + \epsilon $$

to get the system of equations

$$ y_i = \beta_0+\beta_1 x_i +\beta_2 x_i^2 + \epsilon, \quad i=1,2,\dots, n $$

then you will get the matrix.

Comment: I am not quite sure i understand how exactly..

Comment: Will the dimensions always be the same for different methods?

Comment: what should n be, bear in mind that datafile contains the answer, how am i supposed to know that its a 82x3 and something else ?

Comment: @John: $n$ is the dimension of the two vectors.

Comment: But how do i know that the matrix A is a 82x3 matrix? 
It seems a bit odd to me.. ?